# Is there a better way to style fields?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm learning twig and using it to format and style my fields. The problem I am running into is that I need to create a new twig template for each individual field.

In the example picture, I have `field--parent-task.html.twig`which allows me to edit 1 field (or the first field), but I will need to create 6 more templates with identical code structure, just to style and move the fields around.

[image]

Is there a more efficient way to do this? In the end, I will have 7 templates just to target different fields, but yet they are all on the same page. I know I can target classes, say `field__label`, but that is not what I need, since I will be moving these fields around, giving them unique positions on the page.

If it cannot be done and this is how it is in D8, that is fine, I will deal with it. But if not, is there a better approach? So I don't end up having a endless list of field templates just to add/tweak a few css styles?

Comment: There are [multiple template suggestions for fields](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21field.html.twig/8.2.x) and there are [multiple](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/use.html) [different](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html) [ways](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html) [of](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) [reusing](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/include.html) [code](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/source.html) in Twig

Comment: This wouldn't be Drupal if there weren't countless other options. Two of the most common ones would be to install a module to add the css classes in UI or use a preprocess hook to add the attributes in PHP. You have to be more specific in what direction you want to go and the specific problem you need to solve.

Comment: Yet another way, if it's a node, use **node--[content-type].html.twig** and print all 7 fields there.

Comment: Is your theme extending classy? It sounds like your field template may be missing classes that wrap the output. That said, there’s so many ways you could do this that there’s no one way to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a project that needed some specific markup for different fields, using field.html.twig only at least saved managing multiple files.

**field.html.twig:**

```
{%
  set themeGroupOne = [
    'first_field',
    'second_field',
  ]
%}

{%
  set themeGroupTwo = [
    'third_field',
    'fourth_field',
  ]
%}

{# field markup option #}
{% if field_name in themeGroupOne %}

  {% for item in items %}
    {{ item.content }}
  {% endfor %}

{# field markup option #}
{% elseif field_name in themeGroupTwo %}

  {% for item in items %}
    {{ item.content }}
  {% endfor %}

{# Final option, default field template #}
{% else %}

{% if label_hidden %}
<span{{ attributes.addClass('field', field_type | clean_class, field_name | clean_class) }}>
  {% if multiple %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <span{{ item.attributes.addClass('field-item', field_type | clean_class ~ '-item', field_name | clean_class ~ '-item') }}>{{ item.content }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {{ item.content }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</span>
{% else %}
<label{{ title_attributes.addClass(field_type | clean_class, field_name | clean_class) }}>{{ label }}</label>
<span{{ attributes.addClass('field', 'with-label', field_type | clean_class, field_name | clean_class) }}>
  {% if multiple %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <span{{ item.attributes.addClass('field-item', field_type | clean_class ~ '-item', field_name | clean_class ~ '-item') }}>{{ item.content }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {{ item.content }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</span>
{% endif %}
```

*Note that the two fields:

- `field.field.paragraph.paragraph_type.field_h2`
- `field.field.node.node_type.field_h2`

will both register as `field_name == 'field_h2'` in **field.html.twig**, making it even easier to theme fields across your site.